# (403) Forbidden when calling console app that generates file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

We have a simple console app that generates a TXT file and sends it as an email to a list of users. This console app is in the Remote Server on drive E. The console app works; if I go to the Remote Server and I run it from a command-line, the file is generated and email is sent. Drive E is a local drive in the Remote Server.

Now I need to run the EXE from a webform, so I call it using `System.Diagnostics.Process`, and I deploy to Remote Server. Both `Process.StartInfo.FileName` and `WorkingDirectory` are pointing to E:\. The code is in a button click, so I click the button and I receive the error `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden`:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"cons.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"E:\apps\Program\CFolder";
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
myProcess.Start();
```

In my Workstation, I have a mapping to the E drive of RemoteServer (Y:). The code I use is exactly the same as above, but it's Y:\ instead of E:. So I debug locally, and the file and the email are generated.

I understand it's related to permission issues, but What could the problem be? It seems that in RemoteServer, the webform in C:\inetpub\App\Call.aspx cannot write to E:\ even though C: and E: are local drives and I added `NETWORK SERVICE` and `IIS_IUSRS` to the folder in E:.

I can include the code to the webform instead of calling an EXE, but I prefer calling the EXE since it's already there.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: try using [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see that you're trying to access the path you expected, it will also show you exactly what's failing.

Comment: You're close but grasping at straws. IIS runs under a certain profile and that profile has a certain set of permissions. You mentioned having added Network Service and IIS_IUSRS to have access to E: but... you are wanting to execute code which is a much higher level of permission than just reading or writing a folder. Make sure you know which profile you're running under and whether that profile has the ability to execute processes.

Comment: It uses the default ASP.NET v4.0 app pool with integrated pipeline mode.

Comment: You should not start external processes from your web app. Put the code from your console app into an assembly, Then use that assembly from both the console app and the web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up integrating the code into the website and removing the call to the console application.